# How to append a date string to a folder path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a windows batch file to create a folder base on current date in a base folder, and the assign the full path of the date folder to a variable to be used in the later part of the batch file.

For example, today's full path variable should contains value:

```
E:\BaseFolder\20150921
```

The script is creating the folder fine but I can't figure out how to assign the variable.

```
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ('DATE /t') DO SET CURR = %%c%%a%%b
MD %CURR% 
SET FULLPATH = "E:\\BaseFolder\\"%CURR%
ECHO %FULLPATH%
```

I have tried single back slash, with quote, without quote, single and double forward slash but all don't work.

Any hint on the `set FULLPATH` part?

Comment: You may not have any spaces between the variable name and value when using `SET`.  Also beware that `date /t` is locale-dependent.  For example, on my system it gives "DD/MM/YYYY", not "MM/DD/YYYY".

Comment: Paddy, that is THE VERY HINT! No space. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a portable solution to get the date.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "_timestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

echo TS: %_timestamp%
set "fullpath=E:\BaseFolder\%_timestamp%"
echo fullpath: %fullpath%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, I'm also pretty sure you can't have a space between `SET CURR = whatever`. When I ran your code it didn't produce a date, nor did it set the full path.

```
::mmddyyyy, change as you wish to suit your needs    
SET CURR=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~-4%
MD %CURR%
SET FULLPATH=E:\BaseFolder\%CURR%
ECHO Curr: %CURR%
ECHO full path %FULLPATH%
```